# Finite Group generated by the union of its Sylow $p_i$-subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

> Let $\lbrace P_i : i\in I \rbrace $ be a set of Sylow subgroups of a finite group G, one for each prime divisor $p_i$ of $|G|$. Show that $G$ is generated by $\bigcup P_i$.

from Rotman "An Introduction to the theory of groups" pag.81 n.4.10

my attempt was to demonstrate that $\langle P_1,\dots,P_j \rangle \cap P_{j+1} = 1_G$ but i know how,to prove this only in the ( trivial ) abelian case (in that case is easy to demonstrate the entire exercise)

I tried by contradiction: let $b \in \langle P_1,\dots,P_j \rangle \cap P_{j+1} $ so the order of $b$ is a power of $p_{j+1}$ but in $ \langle P_1, \dots,P_j \rangle $ there are lots of elements and i don't found the way to get an absurd.

Any hint will be appreciate, even different and more elegant solutions :)

Comment: Thanks to all, using yours (identical :) ) hint it was easy, just forget about lagrange, my fault

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: If a finite group $G$ has a subgroup $H$ then the order of $G$ is divisible by the order of $H$ (Lagrange).

Consider the group generated by all the $P_i$ - what can you say about its order?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Calculate the order of the subgroup $U$, which is generated by all $P_i$. What is the order of a $p$-Sylow-group of $U$ for any $p$?