# Intermediate subgroup between closed subgroups of profinite group is closed?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-number-theory, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a profinite subgroup. And $K ,H$ be closed subgroups of $G$ such that

1. $K \vartriangleleft H$ and $(H:K) < \infty $
   .
2. $K
   \subseteq B \subseteq H$ (subgroups)

Then $B$ is closed in $G$?

This question originates from the following statement in Neukirch, Algebraic Number Theory, p.301 (We assume knowledge of Abstract Galois Theory in his book. If additional explanation is needed, then I am willing to.)

[image]

[image]

My tiral for understanding is the underlined statement.
I understand the underlined statement as finding a subextension $M|K$(meaning as Neukirch's book p.275) of $L|K$ such that $G(L|M)$ ($L|M$ is Galois) is a p-Sylow subgroup of $G(L|K)$.
Then my argument is as follows ;

Attempt : We are given a profinite group $G$ (c.f. Neukirch's book, p.275) and finite galois extension $L|K$ ; that is, indices of closed subgroups $G_L$, $G_K$ of $G$ such that $G_L$ is normal in $G_K$ and $(G_K : G_L)$ is finite.
Now, let $S_p \subseteq G(L|K):=G_K/G_L$ a $p$-Sylow subgroup and $\pi : G_K \to G(L|K):=G_K/G_L$ be the natural proejction. Let $B:= \pi ^{-1}(S_p)$.
Then, note that
$$G_L \subseteq B \subseteq G_K$$

So, if $B$ is closed in $G$, then we let $G_M := B$ (c.f. also p.275 in his book).
Then $M|K$ is a subextension of $L|K$ and we are done. So is $B$ really closed in $G$?

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[B:K] < \infty$, so $B$ is the union of a finite number of translations of $K$, which is closed, so $B$ is closed.

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @Plantation you will find this technique (writing a supergroup as a union of translations of the subgroup) very useful

Comment: O.K. I will keep in mind ~